# Are these withering leaves a problem?

Tags: diseases, shrubs

Some of the leaves in the center of this bush are not doing well.

[image: plant with white stains]

Is this a serious problem, and what can I do to help them bush?

Comment: Looks like rhododendron. When I grew them in zone 5 they were trouble free. They do not like full sun and do like moisture . My guess is water might help.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have insects that are chewing them.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact the you provided a good picture I can't tell if this is an insect problem or someone being careless with whitewash.

I suggest giving the plant a good hose down with water.  If you have a hose end sprayer add a touch of dish soap and then rinse with just water.

If it washes off then it was whitewash, if it comes back then it could be [mealybug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug) but it does not show the classic signs of cottony tufts.

Either way a spray of five ml of dish soap to one liter of water will control most soft bodied insects if you are persistent and repeat the application at five day intervals at least twice more.